# How to restrict the data validation for name field

Tags: formula, validation, validation-rule, data, regular-expressions

I have name field which should take only one space between two words.
There shouldnt be any number, special characters or more than one space.

```
(REGEX( Name ,".*\\d+\\.*"))
```

Currently I am just restricting the  validation to check for numbers in name field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following expression:

```
REGEX(Name, ".*([^a-zA-Z _-]+|\\s{2,}).*")
```

The above expression matches any number of characters before and after a match on any character not in the whitelisted set (alphabetic characters, space, underscore, and dash), or two or more consecutive whitespace characters.